# Is it possible to see Linux files from Windows if they are installed on one machine?

Tags: linux, windows, security, filesystems

I am going to partition disk on my laptop and install Ubuntu and Windows 10 separately. I am going to work with and store leak-critical files on Ubuntu (like private keys and etc.) and do usual tasks on Windows 10. I assume that if I get some virus on Windows 10 it would not get access to files on Ubuntu. Am I right? Thanks!

Comment: Encrypt your private keys with strong passwords. You could also encrypt other critical files, however if you encrypt whole partition and then allow access to your user account through automatic decryption mechanisms malware will also be able to access content of encrypted files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how much effort the attacker/virus writer is willing to go to.

Windows doesn't understand linux filesystems, so unless a third party driver is installed the content of linux filesystems will not be visible through the windows filesystem APIs.

However, if the attackers software is running with sufficiently high privilages it can access the underlying partition directly. The malware could include it's own implementation of common Linux filesystems and use it to search for valuable files on Linux partitions.

Comment: Whilst this is theoretically correct, I have never heard of a virus that can jump operating systems like this.

Answer (score 1):

An attacker that has access to your Windows machine WILL have access to the files on Ubuntu. Only way to mitigate that is by encrypting your Ubuntu partition.

Comment: Likewise an attacker that access to your Ubuntu machine will have access to your files on Windows.  Only way to mitigate that is by using Bitlocker and/or VeraCrypt

Comment: This is incorrect. Windows cannot natively read ext4 file systems.

Comment: @Darren True, but it is trivial to install an ext4 driver into Windows, and the attacker will be able to see the partition without the driver. If the asker is doing this whole exercise for security, then they shouldn't rely on default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If you install [ext2fsd](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2fsd/) you will be able to mount and access ext2/3/4 partitions from Windows. I use this all the time, though usually in read-only mode.

To remove access, simply terminate `ext2fsd`. A virus would have difficulty snooping on the files, as there is no native support for ext*N* file systems, but a destructive virus could delete or reformat the partition.

I don't know whether you will be able to decrypt encrypted files, as I've never tried it. To do so there would need to be a common encryption standard between Windows and Linux: I don't know if such exists.

Answer (score -1):

By default, your Windows installation will use NTFS as the file system and Ubuntu will use ext4. Whilst Ubuntu can read NTFS, Windows cannot read ext4 out of the box. An attack on Windows (such as a virus or hacker) will *not* be able to read the files on your Ubuntu partition. However, the partition itself will be visible and it may be possible to format or delete the partition.

Comment: OK, can the downvoters explain which part of this answer they disagree with?